# Webpack Split Chunks Plugin overwriting cacheGroups, regex matching wrong?

Tags: javascript, regex, webpack, webpack-splitchunks

I am attempting to use the Webpack 4 Split Chunks Plugin to create multiple vendor bundles. In this case, I want to create one chunk for react/react-dom, and one chunk for react-router/react-router-dom.

When `cacheGroups` only contains `react` and `vendor`, the build works as expected. The bundle output is:

```
- index
- react
- runtime
- vendors
```

Likewise, if I only have cacheGroups for `router` and `vendor` it works as expected. The output is:

```
- index
- router
- runtime
- vendors
```

In either case when the chunks are created, inspecting shows the correct code for `react` or `router` in their respective cases.

**BUT...** it doesn't work when I include both - in this case only the `router` chunk is created, and `react` code is pushed into the index (src) bundle.

I suspect something is off in the regex patterns that is causing an invalidation of the previous cacheGroup? Any help is appreciated.

Here is my webpack config for splitChunks:

```
splitChunks: {
  cacheGroups: {
    react: {
      test: /[\\/]node_modules[\\/](react|react-dom)[\\/]/,
      name: 'react',
      chunks: 'all'
    },
    router: {
      test: /[\\/]node_modules[\\/](react-router|react-router-dom)[\\/]/,
      name: 'router',
      chunks: 'all'
    },
    vendor: {
      test(mod) {
        // exclude anything outside node modules
        if (!mod.context.includes('node_modules')) {
          return false;
        }

        // exclude react and react-dom
        if (/[\\/]node_modules[\\/](react|react-dom)[\\/]/.test(mod.context)) {
          return false;
        }

        // exclude react-router and react-router-dom
        if (/[\\/]node_modules[\\/](react-router|react-router-dom)[\\/]/.test(mod.context)) {
          return false;
        }

        // return all other node modules
        return true;
      },
      name: 'vendors',
      chunks: 'all'
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: If there is any clarifying information I can provide, please let me know.

Comment: Sidebar why are you excluding react & react-router/react-router-dom?

Comment: Were you able to solve it?

Answer (score 3):

Try to this to your config:

```js
optimization: {
    splitChunks: {
      maxInitialRequests: 4, // This one!
```

The default value of `maxInitialRequests` is 4, so if you have more than 4 bundle, it will somehow merge some of them.

Answer (score 1):

that works for me:

```
router: {
      test: /[\\/]node_modules[\\/](react-router|react-router-dom)[\\/]/,
      name: 'router',
      chunks: 'all',
      priority: 1,
    },
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).